# string.substring vs string.take

Tags: c#, substring

If you want to only take a part of a string, the substring method is mostly used.
This has a drawback that you must first test on the length of the string to avoid errors.
For example you want to save data into a database, and want to cut off a value to the first 20 characters.

If you do  temp.substring(0,20) but temp only holds 10 chars, an exception is thrown.

There are 2 solutions that I see :

1. test on the length, and do the substring if needed
2. use the extension method **Take**

   ```
       string temp = "1234567890";
       var data= new string( temp.Take(20).ToArray());
       --> data now holds "1234657890"
   ```

Is there any disadvantage in terms of speed or memory use , when one uses the Take method.
The benefit is that you do not have to write all those if statements.

Comment: Use a Stopwatch to perform timings. Also, you could write your own extension method for string that does the check.

Comment: I would say that Take will enumerate your String. This might make a huge difference with long strings.

Comment: Performance is sooooo Contextual.

Comment: `temp.SubString(0, Math.Min(20, temp.Length))`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you find yourself doing this a lot, why not write an extension method?

For example:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123456789".Left(5));
            Console.WriteLine("123456789".Left(15));
        }
    }

    public static class StringExt
    {
        public static string Left(this string @this, int count)
        {
            if (@this.Length <= count)
            {
                return @this;
            }
            else
            {
                return @this.Substring(0, count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is indeed my preferred solution, it is more readable than the Take, and uses the power of the substring method.

Thanks all for the information

Answer (score 14):

As Henk Holtermand said, `Take()` creates an `IEnumerator` and then you need the `ToArray()` call.

So, if the **performance** is important in your application, or you will perform substrings several times in your process, the performance could be a problem.

I wrote an example program to benchmark exactly how slower is the `Take()` method here are the results:

Tested with ten million times:

- Time performing substring: **266 ms**
- Time performing take operation: **1437 ms**

And here is the code:

```
    internal const int RETRIES = 10000000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        long timeSubstring = MeasureSubstring(testString);
        long timeTake = MeasureTake(testString);

        Console.WriteLine("Time substring: {0} ms, Time take: {1} ms",
            timeSubstring, timeTake);
    }

    private static long MeasureSubstring(string test)
    {
        long ini = Environment.TickCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < RETRIES; i++)
        {
            if (test.Length > 4)
            {
                string tmp = test.Substring(4);
            }
        }

        return Environment.TickCount - ini;
    }

    private static long MeasureTake(string test)
    {
        long ini = Environment.TickCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < RETRIES; i++)
        {
            var data = new string(test.Take(4).ToArray());
        }

        return Environment.TickCount - ini;
    }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't execute the SubString call, since a GUID is always longer than 4 characters. This invalidates your measurement ;)

Comment: Wow .. 4 years later, but hey ... why not ... You're testing the same string over and over, getting the same results on all of them ... I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44916564/1698987) that will create a list of input strings of varied lengths, and then do the `substring` / `take` with some more entropy. Results suggest `Take` is 6-10 times slower, but still pretty fast (less than 0.0008 ms per `take`).

Answer (score 8):

Firstly I didn't want to answer (as there already are valid answers), but I would like to add something that doesn't fit as a comment:

You're talking about performance / memory issues. Right. As others said, `string.SubString` is way more efficient, because of how it is internally optimized and because of how LINQ works with `string.Take()` (enumeration of chars...etc.).

What no one said is that the main disadvantage of `Take()` in your case is that **it totally destroys the simplicity of a substring**. As Tim said, to get the actual string you want, you'll have to write:

```
string myString = new string(temp.Take(20).ToArray());
```

Damn... this is so much harder to understand than (see Matthew's extension method):

```
string myString = temp.Left(20);
```

LINQ is great for lots of use cases, but shouldn't be used if not necessary. Even a simple loop is sometimes better (i.e. faster, more readable/understandable) than LINQ, so imagine for a simple substring...

To summarize about LINQ in your case:

- worse performances
- less readable
- less understandable
- requires LINQ (so won't work with .Net 2.0 for instance)

Comment: You can use an extension method that encapsulates the string constructor:

`public static string StringJoin(this IEnumerable<char> chars)
{
  return new string(chars.ToArray());
}`

And then use it as follows:

`string myString = temp.Take(20).StringJoin();`

If it is readability, then I think this solution is quite elegant, otherwise the LINQ is far too slow in comparison with `Substring`

Answer (score 3):

A variation of @Daniel answer that seems more accurate to me.
a Guid's length is 36. We're creating a list with a variable length of strings from 1 to 36, and we'll aim for taking 18 with the `substring` / `take` methods, so around half will go through.

The results I'm getting suggest that `Take` will be **6-10 times slower** than `Substring`.

Results example :

```
Build time: 3812 ms
Time substring: 391 ms, Time take: 1828 ms

Build time: 4172 ms
Time substring: 406 ms, Time take: 2141 ms
```

so, for **5 million strings**, doing roughly **2.5 millions operations**, total time is **2.1 seconds** , or around **0.0008564 milliseconds = ~ 1 micro second** per operation. If you feel you need to cut it by 5 for substring, go for it, but I doubt in real life situations, outside of tights loop, you'll ever feel the difference.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Build time: {0} ms", BuildInput());
    Console.WriteLine("Time substring: {0} ms, Time take: {1} ms", MeasureSubstring(), MeasureTake());
}

internal const int RETRIES = 5000000;
static internal List<string> input;

// Measure substring time
private static long MeasureSubstring()
{
    var v = new List<string>();
    long ini = Environment.TickCount;

    foreach (string test in input)
        if (test.Length > 18)
        {
            v.Add(test.Substring(18));
        }
    //v.Count().Dump("entries with substring");
    //v.Take(5).Dump("entries with Sub");

    return Environment.TickCount - ini;
}

// Measure take time
private static long MeasureTake()
{
    var v = new List<string>();
    long ini = Environment.TickCount;

    foreach (string test in input)
        if (test.Length > 18) v.Add(new string(test.Take(18).ToArray()));

    //v.Count().Dump("entries with Take");
    //v.Take(5).Dump("entries with Take");

    return Environment.TickCount - ini;
}

// Create a list with random strings with random lengths
private static long BuildInput()
{
    long ini = Environment.TickCount;
    Random r = new Random();
    input = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < RETRIES; i++)
        input.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(1,r.Next(0,36)));

    return Environment.TickCount - ini;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any disadvantage in terms of speed or memory use when one uses the Take method

Yes. `Take()` involves creating an `IEnumerator<char>` first and, for each char, going through the hoops of `MoveNext()` and `yield return;` etc. Also note the ToArray and the string constructor.

Not an issue for small numbers of strings but in a large loop the specialized string functions are a lot better.

Comment: yup. yiled returns. loveliness of linq => yield return

Answer (score 1):

The `Take` extension method does not create a substring, it returns a query which can be used to create a `Char[]`(ToArray) or a `List<Char>`(ToList). But you actually want to have that substring.

Then you need other methods as well:

```
string  data = new string(temp.Take(20).ToArray());
```

This implicitly uses a `foreach` to enumerate the chars, creates a new char[] (which might allocate too much size due to the doubling algorithm). Finally a new string is created from the `char[]`.

The `Substring` on the other hand uses [optimized methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/895209/284240).

So you pay this little convenience with memory which might be negligible but not always.